# The transaction has been reverted to the initial state

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, revert, remix

I am new to solidity, in fact I have only recently started programming again.

I am trying to launch a smartcontract on remix, but it keeps reverting.

I get the following error:

The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

If anyone can help, I would be most grateful.

Thanks

Chris.

code below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


contract Reward {

 uint public Holdercount = 0;
 uint public totalsupply = 1000000000 * 10 **18;
 string public name = "Reward";
 string public symbol = "RW";
 uint public decimals = 18;
 address public creater;
 uint public tax = 10;
 uint public createdtime;

 struct Holder {
 address Holderaddress;
 uint Balance;
 uint Number;
 uint Purchasetime;
 bool Boughtbefore;
 }

event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
event reward(address receiver, uint amount);

mapping(address => Holder) public Holders ;
address[] public holderlist;

constructor() {
Holdercount += 1;
Holder memory newholder = Holder(msg.sender,totalsupply,Holdercount,block.timestamp,true);
Holders[msg.sender] = newholder;
creater = Holders[msg.sender].Holderaddress;
createdtime = block.timestamp;
holderlist[0] = msg.sender;
}


function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
    require (value >= 10000, 'minimum transfer amount 10000');
    require(Holders[msg.sender].Balance >= value, 'balance too low');
    uint transferamount = value - ((value*tax)/100);
    if(Holders[to].Boughtbefore){
    Holders[to].Balance += transferamount;
    Holders[msg.sender].Balance -= value;}
    if(!Holders[to].Boughtbefore){
    Holder memory Newholder = Holder(msg.sender,transferamount,Holdercount,block.timestamp,true);
    Holders[to] = Newholder;
    Holders[msg.sender].Balance -= value; 
    holderlist.push(to);
    }
    if(Holders[msg.sender].Balance == 0){
        removefromlist(Holders[msg.sender].Number);
        delete Holders[msg.sender];
        Holdercount -= 1;

    }
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
    distribute(transferamount);
    return true;
    }



function distribute(uint _charge) internal{
require(Holdercount >1, "unable to distribute");
uint _reward = _charge/Holdercount;
for(uint i=0; i<Holdercount; i++){
    Holders[holderlist[i]].Balance += _reward;
    emit reward(Holders[holderlist[i]].Holderaddress, _reward);
}
}

function removefromlist (uint index) internal {
for (uint i = index; i < holderlist.length; i++){
holderlist[i] = holderlist[i +1];
}
holderlist.pop();
}

function balancecheck(address checkaddress) public returns (uint){
    return Holders[checkaddress].Balance;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

There was a problem with the array statement in the constructor function.

```
holderlist[0] = msg.sender;
```

I changed it to:

```
holderlist.push(msg.sender);
```

This solved the issue.